# Change file before calculating hash in manifest msbuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm working on old .net 4.5 app. I have MSBuild which performs some tasks and generates manifest file. Laster on this manifest file is used in ClickOnce installation, I would like to change the content of it after buidl but before manifest file with calculated hashes is generated.

I wanted to add custom step to override content of one file after build/during build based on some conditions.

In order to do that I added post build event. It works great but generated manifest file which is then used by ClickOnce installation has already calculated different hash for this file and installation fails.

Is there any way to replace file content before hash in manifest file is calculated but preserve original file content for next builds?

Comment: Can you share some code? Other than that, you could run `mage.exe` to create an updated manifest.